# Putting a button in the middle of an image and text below

Tags: html, css

I am having css problem here. I am trying to place my play button at the middle of an image and couple of text lines beneath it. What I am chasing is similar to an audio player where the image is the cover picture, the button is the play icon and the 3lines of texts. I dont even know where to start. my html are...

```css
.track {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px
}

.track-info {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  height: auto;
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="track">
  <img src="image.jpg">
  <div>
    <button>playbutton</button>
  </div>
  <div class="track-info">
    <h3>Artist Name</h3>
    <h4>Track title</h4>
    <h5>Any text</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have played a round with left, right and top margins but it Looks like positioning and displays is the only way to solve it for me

Comment: should the text be in the middle under the button, or just the button in the middle and the text is under the image?

Comment: Hi Again Micheal coker. Yes the lines of texts should come just below the button. both button and texts should be on the image(ie the image is like  a main wrapper and all the other contents are centered in it)

Comment: Hello again :) Submitted an answer - is that what you're going for? Wasn't sure if you wanted the button in the center and the text underneath, or if you wanted the button and text in the center (so the button would be a little above center and the text would go a little below center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the button in a text absolutely positioned to the center, then absolutely position the track info below that centered element. That will put the button in the center, with the text centered underneath.

You can also make the image a background image of `.track` though I didn't do that. Commented out the CSS you would use to do that, then you would remove the `img` from your html and the `img` block in your css.

```css
.track {
  /* background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat / cover; */
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: url('') 0 0 no-repeat / cover;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.track-info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width:160px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="track">
  
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg">

  <div class="centered">
    <button>playbutton</button>
    <div class="track-info">
      <h3>Artist Name</h3>
      <h4>Track title</h4>
      <h5>Any text</h5>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @MichelleDimwaite I am curious why you chose zero's solution. It seems overly complicated and specific. I'm not encouraging you to change your answer or anything, just curious why that works better so I know going forward answering questions for folks.

Comment: Heya @Micheal Coker: I m very sure your method worked well and easier for me. and thats the one i am implementing.. Maybe I confirmed  a different methiod, pretty new out here and sometimes you r not very sure which answer is from which user. Thanks buddy and your method works really well. And you ve been very helpful in my last 2 questions here... Much appreciation..

Comment: @MichelleDimwaite oh awesome, you're welcome. In my honest, objective as I can be opinion, I think this is the best solution, too. You can always change the solution by checking the check mark by our answers, so you can select mine if it's the best answer. That's something you should always be sure to do since this post will live forever, and the best solution should be at the top for future readers. And if someone comes along tomorrow or next month and offers an even better solution, you should update the solution again and choose that one.

Comment: Sorry Mike.. I just figured out now that I didnt select the answer I am implementing. Sorry about that..And yes, i just checked the one that worked best for me..

Comment: @MichelleDimwaite it's all good. Thanks for doing that, it's good for the community.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the button to be in the middle of the image, with the text below, you'll want the button to have `position: absolute`, along with a `top` and `left` offset that is a calculation based on the size of the image. I've given the button `<div>` the class of `.play` for clarity in this example :

```css
.track img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.track .play {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc((400px / 2) - (22px / 2)); /* Half image height minus half button height */
  left: calc((400px / 2) - (78px / 2)); /* Half image width minus half button width */
}
```

```html
<div class="track">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
  <div class="play">
    <button>playbutton</button>
  </div>
  <div class="track-info">
    <h3>Artist Name</h3>
    <h4>Track title</h4>
    <h5>Any text</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with positioning you should try :

```css
.image-div {
position: relative;
}
.button {
position: absolute;
top :150px;
left:190px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-div">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5dsGWM5XGdg/hqdefault.jpg"/>
<button class="button">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> For align Horizontal use `margin:0 auto`
>
> For align Vertical use Formula:`((parent's width /2) + (width / 2))`

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
} 

 .track {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;

 }

.center {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;/*align Horizontal */
  top: -300px;/*align Vertical:((parent's width /2) + (width / 2))*/
}

.track-info {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
 <div class="track">
  <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/cute-bunny-1600x900.jpg">
  <div class="center">
    <div>
      <button>playbutton</button>
    </div> 
    <div class="track-info">
      <h3>Artist Name</h3>
      <h4>Track title</h4>
      <h5>Any text</h5> 
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```